# Некорректно отображаются иконки из блока «Поделиться»

Tags: javascript, ya-share2

[image: отображение иконок на сайте]

Установил ya-share2 и рядом с иконками стал отображаться текст.
Когда стояла предыдущая версия, такого не было... Как убрать этот текст?

новый:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8" async="async"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus"></div>
```

было:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share/share.js" charset="utf-8" async="async"></script>
<div class="yashare-auto-init" data-yashareL10n="ru" data-yashareType="none" data-yashareQuickServices="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,twitter,gplus"></div>
```

Comment: Стили сайта переопределяют стили блока, делая элемент `title` видимым. На каком сайте воспроизводится проблема?

Comment: Вы как-то изменяли стили этого блока? Почему на скриншоте такой ахтунг со шрифтом?

Comment: на сайте http://divanykresla.ru/ - движок magento
специально стили не переопределял. и старая версия работает нормально title никуда не выводятся..

Comment: 99%, что проблема из-за `#footer_bottom .noHover span {
    display: inline-block;
}` styles.css, строка 430